# HLSL - How can i add multiple layers on a mesh ( moss/fur shader)

Tags: shader, hlsl

i want to achieve a moss effect usilg a classic multi-layered mesh.

so, i need to replicate the same mesh N times with a slight displacement (inflate it along normals) and draw each time a pixel so, we have a moss/fur effect.

what is the best/cheaper way to do that ?
multiple passes ?
geometry shader ?

thanks a lot

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would want a custom shader rather than multiple meshes.

Comment: Hi, could you explain please ?

Comment: in fact i want to create shells arounf the existing mesh

Answer (score 0):

i think i found a suitable solution, here it is :
https://timothythiecke.wordpress.com/portfolio/hlslshader/
Thanks for reading